# Unlocking a "read only" registry entry in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

My registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` is being locked up by malicious software. My home page is changed and I can't change it back because of the entry's permission being set to "READ ONLY".

How can I remove the lock and change the key?

Comment: I solved by myself! Right Click on the entry and select "Permissions"->"Advanced"->"Owner". There it is "SYSTEM". Change it to "Administrators". Then I can change now. Damn that malicious software!!!

Comment: consider writing this as an answer yourself, instead of a comment, as this solved your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it:

1. Right-click on the entry and select "Permissions"→"Advanced"→"Owner".
2. Change "SYSTEM" to "Administrator"

Now the entry can be modified.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are actually "infected" by some malware, but don't worry it doesn't seem to be important.

You should use [HiJackThis](http://www.hijackthis.de/) to determine which malware is on your computer (install, launch, copy the result and paste it in the main page form to examine it) or use some spyware removal tool (Ad-Aware/Spybot), an antivirus **AND** CCleaner, several times to be sure your computer is clean. You can then check it again with HiJackThis.